# what extension in vscode that enable me to see the function hints when i type one function?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently using VScode editor for python, but I am not sure why I can not see the function hint when I type function's name.

Anyone knows what extension can I install to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the extension [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and in **User Settings.json** set

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

which can provide awesome features like docstrings, auto-completion and so on.